# Dynamic calls to WinRT interfaces

Tags: c++, c, windows-runtime

I'd like to make dynamic (i.e. reflection-based) calls to WinRT objects, from C or C++. I will assume that I have winmd files available at run-time, so that I can find out what the methods are and what parameters they take.

In OLE Automation, IDispatch was then available to make the actual calls. However, WinRT objects don't support IDispatch. How can I then make calls? Do I need some kind of FFI library that will allow to dynamically pass the parameters, according to the COM calling convention of the processor? Or do I really need "static" class/struct declarations (for C/C++)?

*Edit*: The target system is a metro-style app. That precludes solutions involving banned APIs.

Comment: There are a finite set of .winmd files - why don't you generate wrappers for every single one using a tool of your own make - then you can use regular reflection.

Comment: The set of winmd files is not finite: every "component DLL" a user may create produces a new winmd file, and I can know  the whole set only at runtime. But yes - this option is what I mean by "static" declarations.

Comment: You could make a tool which generates a wrapper assembly, call the tool at runtime to generate the wrapper for the new component, load the assembly dynamically, and then use reflection. The tool is useful on its own (if indeed it doesn't already exist) and users can leverage their existing reflection knowledge rather than learning something new.

Comment: Ben: that possibly can't work in a metro app, can it? I would need a compiler on the target system. Notice that I talk about C and C++, not C#.

Comment: If you can load random DLLs never seen before, you can call an external tool. If you've seen them before you have had the opportunity to create a wrapper and compile against it. Also I don't see metro in your question. What's your use-case for this anyway?

Comment: A few comments on [CxxReflect](http://seaplusplus.com/2012/04/26/cxxreflect-native-reflection-for-the-windows-runtime/), which was mentioned in a now-deleted answer:  As you said, there is no support for invocation on ARM. Yet. I just don't have an ARM device running Windows 8 yet, so I haven't been able to implement the thunks.  Better documentation is forthcoming, along with examples and better tests :-).  I've focused mostly on instantiation and not so much on generalized dynamic invocation, but the latter is quite possible; it's just not been my first priority.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Ben: in the specific case, loading arbitrary DLLs is not possible,as loading of DLLs, just as creation of new processes, is mostly banned in a metro app.

Comment: So any component you want to reference is one which was known at compile time, yes? Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible to build what you're describing - under the covers that's exactly what the Chakra Javascript engine does with winrt metadata and is similar to what the CLR does.  Both of these language projections discover the APIs at runtime and build up the low level assembly to make this happen.

It's a lot of work and isn't particularly pleasant but it's absolutely technically possible.  The windows metadata contains all the information needed to create stubs for the APIs and structures.

Comment: Do you happen to know how they achieve that? E.g. Do they generate machine code on-the-fly? Or use some MS APIs designed for that interfacing?

Comment: To rephrase: is there an official api (like IDispatch), or do I need to generate machine code "somehow"? (e.g. Using an ffi library?)

Comment: There is no official API - we intentionally removed IDispatch like functionality from winrt because of the overhead it introduces to the API surface (IDispatch based APIs are much slower than direct API calls).  The CLRs solution involves a variant of the existing CLR RCW logic and the Chakra solution is similar to that used by the RPC marshaling engine - which does not require "generating machine code" but does require generating CPU specific stack frames.

Comment: @LarryOsterman, so to answer his underlying question, he cannot do this from a Metro app because it requires unsafe code?

Comment: Metro apps can run unsafe code.  They can't call VirtualProtect and a host of other windows APIs but I believe that all the APIs they need to call are available.  Note: I wasn't joking when I said this would not be easy.  It will require processor specific inline assembly and a host of other stuff.  But it should be doable.